# Transmission loses preferences

Tags: gnome, 13.04, transmission

I'm running Ubuntu Gnome 13.04. I installed a shell extension Transmission daemon indicator but that requires transmission to be started at the system startup. So I made an entry in startup application for transmission pointing to /usr/bin/transmission-gtk. The transmission starts perfectly but I think it loses it's preferences that is it starts up from the beginning asking to accept the security notice. This also unchecks the Enable web client and Show transmission icon in notification area.
I think I'm not setting up the startup entry. Please help with the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you're using version 2.77 of Transmission. I had the exact same problem. Transmission was losing preferences everytime I started it. I am NOT using any extensions, however. I managed to work around losing the preferences by going to ~/.config/Transmission and actually editing the settings.json file manually. I simply opened up my file using gedit and changed my settings there and saved it. After doing this, when I open up Transmission, all my settings are saved. Hopefully that works for you. I suspect this is a bug of some sort...

Comment: I am experiencing the same problem but, Transmission overwrites `settings.json` with default values on startup.